# Java Applet on OS X - FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)

Tags: java, macos, file, applet, filenotfoundexception

My applet works perfectly on Windows 7 (in both the IDE and in Firefox after deployment to a webpage as a signed `jar`) but throws a `FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)` when run on OS X (in both the IDE and Firefox).

The exception occurs when it tries to create a new `FileOutputStream` `fos` with the new `File` `keyCopy`:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(sslKeyRingClass[0]);
if (is != null) {
    keyCopy = new File("/" + sslKeyRingClass[0]);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyCopy);
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buf, 0, read);
    }
    fos.close();
    is.close();
}
```

It does work from the IDE (Eclipse) on both Windows and OS X after removing the explicit file separator `/`:

```
keyCopy = new File(sslKeyRingClass[0]);
```

but throws the same `FileNotFoundException` on both Windows and OS X when deployed as a `jar`.

Using the system dependent separator
`keyCopy = new File(File.separator + sslKeyRingClass[0]);` gives the same results as the explicit '/';

I'm using a policy file with AllPermission in Eclipse, the `jar` is signed with a valid code signing certificate and the manifest has the `Permissions: all-permissions` attribute.

Can anyone explain why the `FileNotFoundException (Permission Denied)` is thrown and perhaps suggest a solution that will work cross-platform?

Comment: `keyCopy = new File("/" + sslKeyRingClass[0]);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyCopy);`Does that work on OS X from a commend line app.?

Comment: *"sslKeyRingClass[0] is defined in the applet code so not available from the command line.."* OK, try it as `keyCopy = new File("/SomeTypicalStringFromsslKeyRingClassArray" ); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyCopy);`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, should have thought of that ;) I wrote a v basic java prog in emacs and ran it from the terminal. It throws the same FileNotFoundException (Permission denied) when I use `new File("/SomeTypicalStringFromsslKeyRingClassArray" )` but it works when I use `new File("SomeTypicalStringFromsslKeyRingClassArray" )` i.e. without the '/'

Comment: Bing!  ... I thought I'd heard somewhere that OS X had a different idea of 'root drives' but was not sure of the details (or whether it was relevant here).  As a 'workaround' (or indeed a better overall strategy), I would suggest putting the file in `user.home`, which is a path that any trusted Java app. should be able to access for both read and write.

Comment: Thanks again Andrew, this was a great call and really very much appreciated. I've now added `private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
private static String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");` and use these properties to set the path for `keyCopy`. Works a treat on both windows and mac in the IDE and browser.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Andrew, use user.home instead of "/" for the file path. Final solution was to use "os.name" to determine the user os and then "user.home" for the path. This works on both windows and mac.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)